# delete single relation from many-to-many relationship ef6 c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to delete a single item (relation) from my many-to-many relationship but everything i've tried doesn't seem to work.

This is my db:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
      public IDbSet<Playlist> Playlists {get; set;}
      public IDbSet<Song> Songs {get; set;}

      //constructor

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
            //some coding for setting up keys and properties

            //relation
            modelBuilder.Entity<Playlist>().HasMany(playlist => playlist.Songs).WithMany(song => song.Playlists);

            //removed cascading
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvetion>();
      }
}
```

I've instantiated my objects like

```
public class Song 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    //some properties
    public List<Playlist> Playlists {get; set;}

    //in every constructor i made new List<Playlist>() and assigned it to Playlists prop
}


 public class Playlist
 {
     [Key]
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     //some properties
     public List<Song> Songs {get; set;}
     //I also assigned new List<Song>() to Songs property in every constructor 
 }
```

Now, what I wanna do is to allow user to add/remove `Song` objects to `Playlist` carelessly. I've managed to make async function for adding, but I'm constantly getting various exceptions when trying to remove single `Song` from `Playlist`.
My idea was to remove `playlist` from list of `playlists` in selected `song`, and do the same for `playlist` object and then call the function to validate changes in db:

```
public async Task RemoveSongFromPlaylist()
{
    //await for playlist and song from db

    playlist.Songs.Remove(song);
    song.Playlists.Remove(playlist);
    await db.RemoveRelation(playlist, song);
}


//implementation class for all db doing
public async Task RemoveRelation(playlist, song)
{
     //check if playlist and song even exist in db (only for caution)

     context.Entry(playlist.Songs.First(s => s.Id == song.Id)).State = EntityState.Deleted;
     await context.SaveChangesAsnyc();
}
```

I would really appreciate any tip and help on how to do this, whilst I've struggled so much and tried so many ways but every one of them failed.

Comment: Why does song have List<Playlist>? seems wrong to me. Playlist contains list of songs and not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Thing Song class of yours should not contain

```
List<Playlist>
```

Currently Song contains List of Playlist and Playlist contains List of Songs, you are creating a chain here. Which is a problem I see.

Think of YouTube, when you open playlist, you will see songs. But when you search for songs you don't see playlists that song is contained in

Comment: hm, I wanted to allow users to search songs as many as possible ways, that's why I added every song it's own list of playlists, but I guess I can do without it

but still, when I remove that property, I stil get the same exception: 
Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed.

and it's pointing to the last line in RemoveRelation method (await context.SaveChangesAsync(); )

Comment: If i were you I would pass songs id in function parameter but still, try this `song = playlist.Songs.First(x=>x.Id == song.Id);context.Songs.Attach(song);
context.Songs.Remove(song);
context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Also, why do you have async in every method. Do you know what you are actually doing by using async?

Comment: I tried your way, but still get the same exception...what does even attach does? 
and every method in which I use database I use async waiting, whilst data from database can be hard to reach (at least, that's what I was learned at classes)

Comment: .WithMany(song => song.Playlists) try removing that from your context class

Comment: http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/deleting-data this might also help you understand few more things

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but none of this worked - still throwing exception at 'context.SaveChanges()' 
could the problem be in that i'm dynamically adding/removing playlist - one view in which i have list of songs and every song has 'add to playlist' button, which immediately shows underneath the column 'new playlist' and there every added song has 'remove from playlist' ? i purely doubt it, it doesn't make any sense for it to crash there, but I really feel hopeless right now